# mysqldump common install locations for mac/linux

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to know all the common locations for `mysqldump`. The list I have come up with is as follows:

```
'/usr/bin/mysqldump', //Linux
'/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump', //Mac OS X
'/usr/local/bin/mysqldump', //Linux
'/usr/mysql/bin/mysqldump'; //Linux
```

Often mysqldump isn't in the path, so I am trying to have all the locations to look in. (I am running this from a php script)

Are there any that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried running `find / -name mysqldump -type f -perm /u=x` on first run, then caching the value in a file?

Comment: I haven't tried. I just did this on my Mac and got `find: -perm: /u=x: illegal mode string`

Comment: Looks like an old version of find, try -perm /u+x or -perm /444 or even older -perm +444

Comment: This takes awhile to run and I need this to happen fast. I would rather hardcoded all the possible paths and check if the path is_executable (in php)

Comment: If you installed it from Homebrew (OS X), it would be in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/$version/something` (I don't use mysql, so I don't know the exact path.) If you are on a unix machine, you can also just do `which mysqldump` Though, that would only work if it is in your path.

Comment: I just need the most common places. I am creating a php script that will attempt to backup a database. My target audience is web hosts that use cpanel on linux operating systems.

Comment: In that case I would suggest that you already have the most common locations. However, I did a quick search on the subject, and apparently it is not suggested to use `mysqldump`. People suggest using `/usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy`.

Comment: can't use hot copy as I have innodb, but thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was unable to find any other paths apart from the ones you have given in your question. However, one thing that does come in my mind is that `mysqldump` should, in most cases, be in the same directory as the `mysql` binary. Now, the `mysql` command will be in the path, in most cases, as well.

And, therefore, you can combine the two logics to have the location of the `mysqldump` binary, in most cases, like this:

```
function detect_mysqldump_location() {

  // 1st: use mysqldump location from `which` command.
  $mysqldump = `which mysqldump`;
  if (is_executable($mysqldump)) return $mysqldump;

  // 2nd: try to detect the path using `which` for `mysql` command.
  $mysqldump = dirname(`which mysql`) . "/mysqldump";
  if (is_executable($mysqldump)) return $mysqldump;

  // 3rd: detect the path from the available paths.
  // you can add additional paths you come across, in future, here.
  $available = array(
    '/usr/bin/mysqldump', // Linux
    '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump', //Mac OS X
    '/usr/local/bin/mysqldump', //Linux
    '/usr/mysql/bin/mysqldump' //Linux
   );
  foreach($available as $apath) {
    if (is_executable($apath)) return $apath;
  }

  // 4th: auto detection has failed!
  // lets, throw an exception, and ask the user to provide the path instead, manually.
  $message  = "Path to \"mysqldump\" binary could not be detected!\n"
  $message .= "Please, specify it inside the configuration file provided!"
  throw new RuntimeException($message);
}
```

Now, you can use the above function for your purposes. And, provide a way for the user to provide the explicit path to `mysqldump` binary manually, if the above function throws an error. Should work for your use cases :)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. This worked great. (I modified it a little bit but the `which` command was a good idea.